# convert python data frame to a sql table in databricks

Tags: python, sql, dataframe, databricks

I have a python df that I created from pulling a sharepoint list into databricks. I need to convert the python DF into a SQL table to be able to query it within databricks SQL. Can you convert a python df into SQL table/temp view?

Answer (score 0):

You can create a temporary view:

```
df.createOrReplaceTempView("table_temp")
```

After that, you can query as:

```
SELECT * FROM table_temp
```